# Measuring powdered sugar

Tags: sugar

I have some old recipes that call for a box of powdered sugar. How many cups would that equal ? I buy powdered sugar in  two pound bags.

Comment: If at all possible, measure powdered sugar by weight. It's very susceptible to inaccurate measurement due to packing.

Comment: It might help to summarize one of the recipes. Depending on how old the recipe is, "box" might have a meaning that is no longer used.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess would be one pound, since it's still often sold in stores in 1lb boxes, regardless of brand:

[image: imperial 1lb box] [image]

You can see plenty more like that if you do a [Google image search for [powdered sugar box]](https://www.google.com/search?q=powdered%20sugar%20box&tbm=isch).

As others have pointed out, measuring by volume is inaccurate (one pound could be 3.5 to 4.5 cups), so you'd be best off using a scale, or perhaps measuring your two pound bag into two equal volumes.

That said, if your recipe can tolerate being off by a couple ounces (around half a cup), you could use four cups for a one-pound box.

Answer (score 1):

According to [King Arthur Flour's Master Weight Chart](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/learn/ingredient-weight-chart.html), 1 pound (the most likely size of a box in the US) of unsifted powdered sugar is about 4 cups. As I said in a comment above, I highly recommend weighing powdered sugar instead of measuring it by the cup.

Answer (score 1):

Per [Domino® Sugar](https://www.dominosugar.com/baking-tips-how-tos/measurement-and-conversion-charts),

> The answer to how many cups are in one pound of powdered sugar will vary depending on if your powdered sugar is sifted or unsifted. In general:
>
> 1 pound = 3 1/2 to 4 cups unsifted powdered sugar
> 1 pound = 4 1/2 cups sifted powered sugar

Customarily sold in boxes in the US, as in the illustration provided by @Jefromi, they are one pound/16 ounces. For a 2-pound bag, either measure out 3 1/2 to 4 cups for the recipe or, more straightforward, half of the quantity in the bag.